# Get all rows data of a JQGrid in codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid, code-behind, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm adding some rows data to my JQGrid on client side with javascript :

```
var grid = jQuery("#<%= JQGridMembers.ClientID %>");
var rowKey = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
var newRow = [{ ID: memberId, FullName: memberFullName, Percent: parseInt(percent)}];
grid.addRowData(memberId, newRow);
```

above code works well , but How can I get all inserted rows data (in JQGrid) in code-behind?

Comment: Just one remark: I would you recommend don't use `addRowData` if it is *really required* and there are no other way. The only use case is if you get new rows *along*. For example if the user clicked on "Add" button explicitly and added new data. In case if you get *many rows* and need to clear the old contain and insert new data in the grid the usage of `addRowData` would be the wrong (the slowest) way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get all rows from the grid by

```js
var myData = grid.jqGrid('getRowData');
```

or with respect of

```js
var myData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
```

The last way can be used only with local `datatype` or in case of `loadonce: true`. It returns data not only from the current page, but all data from all pages.

The `getRowData` method use unformatter to *read* the data from all cells of the grid.

Comment: How can you get the data for only the current page if loadonce is set to true?

Comment: @mrshickadance: You can first get all `id` values from the current page. You can use `getDataIDs` for example. Then you can get every data item which corresponds the rowids using `getLocalRow` method. You can push the results in an empty array for example and add `id` property to every data item. In the way you will have full information.

Answer (score 4):

Had encountered a similar problem, below is what I ended up using

```
var data = $("#table-id").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var f_name = data[i].FirstName;
    var l_name = data[i].LastName;
    // blah... blah..
}
```

[Reference](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/jqgrid-getdata-only-returns-data-for-current-page/)