# jqGrid Get all filtered rows from localdata

Tags: jquery, arrays, jqgrid

I am using a jgGrid that has `loadonce: true`.  So all records are loaded once the grid is created.  I also have custom search options, to filter the local data ([this question explains how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749723/jqgrid-filtering-records));

But how can I retrieve all the filtered rows?

I found this question '[get-all-rows-not-filtered-from-jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775115/get-all-rows-not-filtered-from-jqgrid)'.  But I cannot help but wonder, if there is not some form of an array that the jqGrid has that has the results of all the filtered rows?

I know jqGrid has an array for all rows ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749104/get-all-rows-data-of-a-jqgrid-in-codebehind)), but logically one would think that there should be an array for all rows after the filtering has taken place.

So does this array exist, Or should I do what was suggested by Oleg in '[get-all-rows-not-filtered-from-jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775115/get-all-rows-not-filtered-from-jqgrid)'?

I am using jqGrid-4.5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I used Oleg solution in ['get-all-rows-not-filtered-from-jqgrid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775115/get-all-rows-not-filtered-from-jqgrid).  And it worked well.

I also had a quick look at the source code.  Could not make heads or tails of it.  So was not able to found my array that I was looking for.